# Error in dijit.form.FilteringSelect

Tags: dojo, dijit.form

I am creating a dijit.form.FilteringSelect programmatically and trying to populate the data through a JSON file :

```
var stateStore = new dojo.data.ItemFileReadStore({
              url: "states.json"
                });
    var select = new dijit.form.FilteringSelect({
            title:this.response.items[i].DisplayName,
            name:this.response.items[i].Name,
            type:"picklist",
            value: "CA",
            store: stateStore,
            searchAttr: "name"  
    });
dijit.byId("test").domNode.appendChild(select.domNode);
```

But getting the below error :

dijit.form.FilteringSelect TypeError: Unable to get property 'length' of undefined or null reference

Below is the content of json file :

{"identifier": "abbreviation",
"label": "name",
"items": [{ "abbreviation": "AL", "name": "Alabama" }, 
{ "abbreviation": "WY", "name": "Wyoming" }]}

Please guide.

Comment: Your code is missing "stateStore". Please update.

Comment: Apologies, I have updated now

Comment: You have a static stateStore that reads a "states.json" file. But what is "this.response.items" ? It this code wrapped inside a resulting xhr call? Are you sure "this.response.items" is an array and not null?

Comment: Maybe you should create a fiddle to demonstrate the problem.

Comment: Yes, I am getting a response which has an array of JSON. Altough, I am setting tilte and Name though that which is getting set fine. Problem seems to be with the store. Is the format of JSON file correct. ?